# Is this an offshoot of a tree or a separate plant?

Tags: identification, shrubs, desert

Plants native to the [Sonoran Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoran%20Desert) require watering every 6 months. The following plant, which I am not sure is native to the Sonoran Desert or not, was found to thrive in the [Sonoran Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoran%20Desert) solely off rain. What is this plant?

Is this an offshoot of a tree? It sprung up right next to the trunk a young (albeit dead or dormant) tree:
[image: Shrub #6]

Comment: @pnuts Do junipers send out underground shoots?

Comment: Can you post some more photos of the surrounding area? Particularly from the base if the suspected original tree is already pictured?